# Netty 4.0 Flow Control

Tags: netty

Netty 3.x offered [MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.html) which allowed flow control between the I/O thread model and the thread model that would execute the business logic.

Things changed quite a bit in 4.0 API and each handler basically provides its input buffer and can be executed in its own dedicated thread. How can a decoder that's fast and writes to the input buffer of a slower business handler, that runs in a separate thread, be throttled or blocked?

Answer (score 0):

In cr2 you could probably make use of feature allowing to limit inbound buffers, but it would not provide the out-of-box solution to your problem. However, in cr6 this facility is gone. I would like to see an answer to this question as well.

UPDATE:
here is a basic implementation I came up with. Surely there must be a better way though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389396/netty-throttling-reads-example